# Could not find onButtonClick method

Tags: java, android

I have just started learning android. I am getting this error.Please help me fix this.

This is my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sumit.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

    <Button
        android:text="Sum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick (MainActivity)" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my .java file

```
package com.example.sumit.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setText("sumit");

    }
}
```

And I am getting this error.

> E/EGL_emulation: tid 3738: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009
>   (EGL_BAD_MATCH) W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on
>   surface 0x7f0d46d90c40, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>               Process: com.example.sumit.myapplication, PID: 3720
>               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onButtonClick (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3720 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

How do I fix this ?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
```

instead of

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick (MainActivity)"
```

View parameter is passed by android.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick (MainActivity)"
```

replace with :

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
```

Note that with the XML above, Android will look for the onClick method onButtonClick() only in the current Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Well. your `stacktrace` explains it:

> Could not find method onButtonClick (MainActivity)

There's no method with **that** name. the name shouldn't contain the `(MainActivity)` part.

in the .xml, write this:

```
<Button
    android:text="Sum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```